# Serializing an object to a string: why is my encoding adding stupid characters?

Tags: c#, encoding, xml-serialization

I need to get the serialized XML representation of an object as a string.  I'm using the XmlSerializer and a memoryStream to do this.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
  using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(stream,Encoding.UTF8))
  {
    serializer.Serialize(writer, myClass);
    string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    //other chars may be added from the encoding.
    xml = xml.Substring(xml.IndexOf(Convert.ToChar(60)));
    xml = xml.Substring(0, (xml.LastIndexOf(Convert.ToChar(62)) + 1));
    return xml;
  }
}
```

Now just take note of the xml.substring lines for a moment.  What I'm finding is that (even thought I'm specifying encoding on the XmlTextWriter and on the GetString (and I'm using memoryStream.ToArray(), so I'm operating only on the data in the stream's buffer)... the resulting xml string has some non-xml happy character added.  In my case, a '?' at the start of the string.  This is why I'm substring-ing for '<' and '>' to ensure I've only getting the good stuff.

Strange thing is, looking at this string in the debugger (Text Visualizer), I don't see this '?'.  Only when I paste what's in the visualizer into notepad or similar.

So while the above code (substring etc) does the job, what's actually happening here? Is some unsigned byte thing being included and not being represented in the Text Visualizer?

Comment: For future readers:  Yeah, i do realize the '?' isn't really the '?' character but just the representation of the additional character in Notepad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can exclude the BOM by specifying the encoding specifically - i.e. instead of `Encoding.UTF8`, try using:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
  var enc = new UTF8Encoding(false);
  using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(stream,enc))
  {
    serializer.Serialize(writer, myClass);        
  }
  string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
      stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking at is [a Byte Order Mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). It is normal in UTF8!

In short, for my comment fans: They are byte markers that determine the endianness of a string.

What you can do is either use a) ASCII as your encoding, which will drop the byte order marks .. or b) why not leave them in? They do serve a useful function after all for your xml string.

Marc Gravell, below, gives a [third alternative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s064f8w2.aspx) by creating your own encoding object and specify false in the constructor to suppress byte order markers.

Comment: ah, starts making sense. Dark magic indeed!  Is there a better solution other then substring-ing or can I assume that there will always be a BOM at xml[0]?

Comment: Would be an answer if you mentioned and explained BOM in a few words.

Comment: @henk: Reading a single line on the link would already explain it. But indeed, I helpfully duplicated it from Wikipedia.

Comment: Almost right... Roll back if you don't like it. Think Google and SEO.